# How to create coc nvim custom snippets

Tags: vim, neovim, coc.nvim

By following [this](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Create-custom-source#start-with-a-simple-example) guide, I could get a simple snippet working.

```
" vim source for emails
function! coc#source#email#init() abort
  return {
        \ 'priority': 9,
        \ 'shortcut': 'Email',
        \ 'triggerCharacters': ['@']
        \}
endfunction

function! coc#source#email#complete(opt, cb) abort
  let items = ['foo@gmail.com', 'bar@yahoo.com']
  call a:cb(items)
endfunction
```

But I want when user types something like  `afc` and hit enter in the correct item in the menu. What `coc.nvim` should enter to the buffer is following. .

```
() => {

}
```

I don't know what this `triggerCharacters` option is but it certainly not the characters I should enter in the buffer to get the auto completion menu open because it's not showing up in the menu.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guide you linked is not for snippets, but custom source.

Install coc-snippets like:
`:CocInstall coc-snippets`

Then
`:CocCommand snippets.editSnippets` to create a snippet(for filetype open), for example:

```
snippet afc "Description"
    () => {
        ${0:${VISUAL}}
    }
endsnippet
```

then you can trigger it by `afc`.